# Logging failed assumptions in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have a few `assumeTrue()` and `assumeFalse()` declarations in some of my unit tests. I would like to write out a log message if the assumptions are not true, but I don't see an obvious way to do that.

The documentation says that failed assumptions aren't logged because there may be lots of unit tests that are not necessary due to varying configurations, so I assume the logic is there would be unnecessary clutter in the logs,which make sense.

Just wondering how/if people have implemented output messages for failed assumptions in JUnit. The only thing I could think to do was to annotate the unit test class with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` and use a boolean flag that I set pre and post assumption, but that seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This point of the [`Assume` javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) :

> *Failed assumptions are usually not logged, because there may be many*
>   *tests that don't apply to certain configurations.*

concerns the whole class `Assume` and not the possibilities provided by the class.
You can translate it as you should not usually log a failed assumption.

> Just wondering how/if people have implemented output messages for
>   failed assumptions in JUnit.

If you want to ignore a test because an assumption is not respected, it means that its execution doesn't matter in some conditions.  So why would you log it ?
If the test execution matters, you don't use assumption and generally replace the assumptions by the assertions.

Now you have two ways of write a JUnit assumption :

- by not logging it with for example  `public static void assumeTrue(boolean b)`
- by logging it with for example  `public static void assumeTrue(String message, boolean b)`

Of course `assumeFalse()` and `assumeThat()` present similarly flavors.

At last, note that assumptions are used in corner cases (such as Theory where you want to ignore some scenarios or as you don't master the environment used at runtime). So I try to avoid it as much as impossible.